# Java Regex not working - why?

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist, regex-lookarounds

match.matches() returns false. This is odd, because if I take this regex and test String to rubular.com, is shows two matches. What am I doing wrong?

```
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("FTW(((?!ODP).)+)ODP");
    Matcher match = regex.matcher("ZZZMMMJJJOOFTWZMJZMJODPZZZMMMJJJOOOFTWMZJOMZJOMZJOODPZZZMMMJJJOO");

    if (match.matches()) {
        System.out.println("match found");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("match not found");
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`Matcher.matches`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) returns whether or not the *whole region* matches the pattern.

Try using [`find`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) instead. (Certainly with your example, this works fine.)

Answer (score 9):

The `Matcher.matches()` method tries to match the entire string to the pattern. Change your pattern to:

```
".*FTW(((?!ODP).)+)ODP.*"
```

Comment: As java.sun.String documentation "Returns:
true if, and only if, this string matches the given regular expression" so it is true if all string matches all pattern not part of your string.